# multiple groups with the same name regex java?

Tags: java, regex, named-captures

Is there any regular expression api or library for java that can accept multiple groups with the same name in one pattern?

Comment: Why? How would you access each group?

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow OP is probably trying to achieve something like `context1(?<name>regex)context2|context3(?<name>otherRegex)context4`? In this case there will be only one group with name `name` in match.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're trying to match?

Comment: >(ab(?<a>[\w]*)|bs(?<a>[\w]*))

Comment: like above example sometime just one name will be filled and sometimes it is possible to have more than one filled same-name so the best one or the last one should be chosen by regex engine.

Answer (score 4):

This is a very old question, but google brought me here, I found a solution for **PHP** using the `/J` modifier. All details explained here: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html#dupe_names

> In .NET, PCRE (C, PHP, R…), Perl and Ruby, you can use the same group
>   name at various places in your pattern. (In PCRE you need to use the
>   (?J) modifier or PCRE_DUPNAMES option.) In these engines, this regex
>   would be valid:

```
:(?<token>\d+)|(?<token>\d+)#
```

Working example here https://regex101.com/r/h7HJXj/1

Answer (score 1):

alternative of `(ab(?<a>[\w]*)|bs(?<a>[\w]*))`  regex is `(ab|bs)(?<a>[\w]*)`  with same name. check test in the demo link with `(ab(?<a>[\w]*)|bs(?<b>[\w]*))` and `(ab|bs)(?<a>[\w]*)` . these gives you same result.

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/kT9fZ3/1)